What circuits do I need to make an analog synthesizer?
I want to make a simple analog synthesizer at home, please help me.

Raffi, this isn't a discussion forum. Ask one, focused question. Please edit your question or it is likely to be closed as "too broad".

Read the definitive (and original) book on analogue synthesisers, Sound Synthesis – Analog and Digital Techniques, by Terence Thomas, 1942, ISBN: 0-8306-9276-2 (hardback), 0-8306-3276-X (paperback).
I posted the PCB masks (and schematics), from the book, online a few years back, Sound synthesis: The PCBs – Terence Thomas.
You should still be able to pick up a cheap battered copy of the book from online book sellers.
As periblepsis has pointed out, it is also (now) on the Internet Archive, Sound synthesis : analog and digital techniques.

It appears also at the internet archive.

@periblepsis - Ah, that would have saved me a lot of boring scanning work..! However, it was posted only after I'd bought my copy. I update my answer, thanks. :-)

Note that the book is ca. 1990. While more modern than Mr. Thomas himself, it's getting a bit long in the tooth in terms of some specific components, but the general ideas are timeless.

At the minimum a PSU, VCO, VCA and VCF.
